# Understanding Newton's approximation method with an example

Tags: approximation

Let $f(x)=x^2+3x-10$.  If we take $x_0=0$ as the starting point for the Newton method, then the value of $x_2$ is what?

I have tried but it appears I am wrong somewhere as the exercise from where I have taken this problem does not matches my answer of -190/33.

[image]

Comment: Please take note of my edit and consider using MathJAX in the future...

Comment: How do you know you are wrong?  Do you have the answer listed for you somewhere?

Comment: @abiessu There are multiple options to select from, none of which matches the above.

Comment: Your work looks good, it is possible the problem is written incorrectly or may have been adjusted without correcting the set of answers...

Comment: @abiessu There has been a mistake in the calculation as pointed in the answer. Thanks for assuring me that the approach is okay.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your calculation for $x_1$. You should have
$$
x_1 = 0 - \frac{f(0)}{f'(0)} = 0 - \frac{(0)^2 + 3(0) - 10}{2(0) + 3}  = -\left(- \frac{10}{3} \right)=\color{red}{+} \frac{10}{3}
$$
With this correction you should get $x_2 = \frac{190}{87} \approx 2.1839$, where you are indeed approximating the root $x=2$ of $x^2 + 3x -10$.

[image: Graph]